# Multiple jQuery promises in sequential order

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

Basically I want this:

```
function do_ajax_calls(...){
  var d = $.Deferred();

  $.ajax(args).done(function(){

    $.ajax(args).done(function(){

      $.ajax(args).done(function(){
         d.resolve();
      });

    });

  })

  return d.promise();
}
```

But the number of ajax calls depends on the arguments that I pass to the function, which is an array, so I can't use that code.

The function should return a promise that only resolves when the last ajax calls completes. So the function needs to be called like this:

```
 do_ajax_calls(....).done(function(){
   // here is the callback
 })
```

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: I think that with some kind of eval I can pass string that is built before but I'm not sure if that's the best method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons promises are a big deal is because they can be chained.  You can use this to your advantage to iteratively chain additional requests onto the resolution of the previous one:

```
function do_ajax_calls() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var promise = dfd.promise();
    var responses = [];

    function chainRequest(url) {
        promise = promise.then(function (response) {
            responses.push(response);
            return $.ajax(url, { method: 'POST' });
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0, length = arguments.length; i < length; i++) {
        chainRequest(arguments[i]);
    }

    dfd.resolve();

    return promise.then(function (response) {
        return responses.slice(1).concat(response);
    });
}
```

The above code will return a promise ultimately resolving to an array of all of the responses.  If any one of the requests fails, the promise will reject with the first failure.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/br3a2w45/2/)

Comment: It doesn't look like that will work. Those ajax calls in your loop are all fired immediately?

Comment: Sorry for being nitpicky, but I don't think that will work either because that url variable is inside the inner function. I think it will be undefined. I know because I've experienced this issue

Comment: You have a point, though it's not that the variable will be undefined.  I have a dumb race condition in here which I can't see in the fiddle because I sent the same URL each time.  I've fixed it again.

Answer (score 4):

> But the number of ajax calls depends on the arguments that I pass to the function, which is an array

If it's one ajax call per array item

```
function do_ajax_calls(args) {
    return args.reduce(function(promise, item) {
        return promise.then(function() { 
            return $.ajax(args); // should that be item?
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(true));
}
```

The `Promise.resolve(true)` is a "native" promise, i.e. not available in IE, but I'm sure jQuery has an equivalent

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7egcjok/1/) Demo

Answer (score 1):

Here is it [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kunq9vxc/)

```
var counter = 1 ;

function multipleAjax(loop)
{
   if(counter<loop)
   {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'http://mouadhhsoumi.tk/echo.php',
            success:function(data)
            {
                multipleAjax(loop);
                $(".yo").append(data+"</br>");
                counter++;
            }
        });

   }
}
multipleAjax(5);
```

Comment: This answer defeats the point of promises, which is chaining and composability. it's no different than using pure callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.when()` , `Function.prototype.apply()` , `$.map()`

```
function do_ajax_calls(args) {
  return $.when.apply($, $.map(args, function(request, i) {
    return $.ajax(request) // `request` : item with `args` array
  }))
}

do_ajax_calls
.then(function success() {
  console.log(arguments)
}, function err() {
  console.log("err", arguments)
});
```